# writing netbeans RCP apps on scala

Tags: scala, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

Have anyone tried to write a Netbeans RCP application in scala (Instead of Java). The reason for my question there is an API in Scala which wraps JavaFX. Likewise is there any API to make to develop Netbeans RCP based apps written in scala.

Answer (score 1):

For wrapping JavaFX there is [ScalaFX](http://code.google.com/p/scalafx/).  Netbeans Rich Client Platform is not small, and a Scala wrapper seems impractical to me (I am not aware of any); just call the Java code from Scala.  Java/Scala interoperability is generally decent, so while you might occasionally have to write a little bit of Java as an interface, you can pretty much just use Scala for any Java project.

(Getting the build process to work might be a little tricky, though; expect to invest a little time there.)

Comment: Well, Swing isn't small as well, but there is a wrapper for it. We're writing application using Netbeans RCP (around 10k lines of code, excluding empty lines and comments) and so far we haven't written a single line of java code in it. Of course we have our helpers and util which soften some roughness of RCP.

Comment: @om-nom-nom - RCP is larger than Swing.  Also, the Swing wrapper is incomplete (all my projects have to go back to `.peer` at some point), and isn't being fully maintained.  For instance, there are issues with compilation against Java 1.7 vs 1.6 that could have been wrappered over but weren't.

Answer (score -3):

I personally dont see any useful use case to use JVM language to develop NB RCP/Plugin. NB It self provides a IDE where you can use the drag-drop feature, codegen, annotation based IDE to created it. If you want to have a syntax sugar in writing NB RCP then i feel its waste of time where we already have a good IDE. JVM is not going to do any much difference that the existing environment.

If you see that you need a NB like modular, GUI based framework in Scala ecosystem that, I personally feel writing binding wont solve that problem. Scala need some framework like Griffon.

Comment: So how exactly does it answers a question (is there api wrapper for netbeans RCP)? *I personally dont see any useful use case to use JVM language to develop NB RCP/Plugin* Uhm, so you saying you develop for for Netbeans RCP on non-JVM language, or what?